# Reuse a counter for numbering floats

Tags: floats, counters, newfloat

I can’t find how to number floats created with `\newfloat` using an existing counter (like `sibling=theorem` but for `\newfloat`). Any idea?

**MWE**:

[image]

```
\documentclass[options]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,sibling=theorem]{lemma}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Protocol}{htbp}{lop}[theorem]

\begin{document}
\section{My theorems}

\begin{theorem}
  Blabla
\end{theorem}


\begin{lemma}
  Lemma can use sibling to be numbered with the same counter as theorem.
\end{lemma}

\begin{Protocol}\caption{I want it to be 1.3, not 1.2.1}
  But I can't find how to do it for custom floats.
\end{Protocol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense to number a float environment with the counter of a non-floating environment. The numbers will get out of sync. Try `\begin{Protocol}[t]` to see the problem.

Comment: Hum, interesting. And what if I’m fine with using [H] to force a non-floating environment? (actually if you know a robust way to create a similarly styled element that automatically cut at new page while being compatible with `\cref{}`a I’m interested). (and actually, if I put `\begin{Protocol}[t]`, I actually get what I would expect: the numbering should reflect the position in the original document, not in the page.

Comment: you want a new theorem-like environment, not a float. So don't use a float package to create it (and using H is only cheating).  To style it use either thmtools, or if you want something fancy check the tcolorbox package.